# C: Finding and tallying duplicates in large array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm in an introductory C programming class and in our homework our professor asked us to write a program that generates a one-thousand-number array and store random numbers (ranging from 5 to 15) in it.  Then, it needs to display how many times each number occurred (among other computations).  I have managed to do all this, but in a very inefficient way.  As you can see in my code, I've used a bunch of **if** statements where I could have probably used a **for** loop.  Can you please help me make this code better?  I can't use pointers or rearrange the array.  THANK YOU!

```
main()
```

{
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("This program generates a one-thousand-number array with random values\n"
            "ranging from 5 to 15.  It also calculates the sum of all these numbers,\n"
            "their average, and tallies up each number.\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

```
int i,count5=0,count6=0, count7=0, count8=0, count9=0,
count10=0, count11=0, count12=0, count13=0, count14=0, count15=0, sum = 0;
float avg;

int a[1000] = {0};
srand(time(NULL));

for(i=0; i<=999; i++)
{
    a[i] = (rand()%11)+5;

    if(a[i] == 5)
    {
        count5 = count5++;
    }
    if(a[i] == 6)
    {
        count6 = count6++;
    }
    if(a[i] == 7)
    {
        count7 = count7++;
    }
    if(a[i] == 8)
    {
        count8 = count8++;
    }
    if(a[i] == 9)
    {
        count9 = count9++;
    }
    if(a[i] == 10)
    {
        count10 = count10++;
    }
    if(a[i] == 11)
    {
        count11 = count11++;
    }
    if(a[i] == 12)
    {
        count12 = count12++;
    }
    if(a[i] == 13)
    {
        count13 = count13++;
    }
    if(a[i] == 14)
    {
        count14 = count14++;
    }
    if(a[i] == 15)
    {
        count15 = count15++;
    }

    sum = sum + a[i];

}

printf("Sum of entire array = %d\n",sum);

avg = sum/1000.0;

printf("Average of values in array = %.2f\n\n",avg);

printf("Fives:        %d\n",count5);
printf("Sixes:        %d\n",count6);
printf("Sevens:       %d\n",count7);
printf("Eights:       %d\n",count8);
printf("Nines:        %d\n",count9);
printf("Tens:         %d\n",count10);
printf("Elevens:      %d\n",count11);
printf("Twelves:      %d\n",count12);
printf("Thirteens:    %d\n",count13);
printf("Fourteens:    %d\n",count14);
printf("Fifteens:     %d\n\n",count15);
```

}

Comment: "I have managed to do all this", then you should go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com. And please indent your code first.

Comment: Whoa - you know, in C you *are* allowed to make more than one array!

Comment: Declare: `int count[11] = {0};` then in the `for` loop replace all the `if` statements with the single line: `count[a[i]-5]++;`